# android server how to know client is disconnect or close

Tags: java, android, sockets, client-server

i have two android device, A is server , B is client , and connect with socket ,
how do server/client  know each other is disconnect or close  ,

i have try isconnect(), but not useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the peer has disconnected normally:

- `read()` will return -1
- `readLine()` will return null
- `readObject(),` `readUTF()`, `readXXX()` for any XXX will throw `EOFException

If the peer has disconnected abnormally, the connection has gone bad, etc, any read or write method will throw an `IOException,` except that a read without a read timeout may block forever: this is why you should always use a read time (via `setSoTimeout()`).

`isConnected()` only tells you whether you ever connected or accepted the socket. `isClosed()` only tells you whether you ever closed it. These APIs tell you about the `Socket`, not the *connection.*